# Way to open graphical console of KVM VM in fullscreen in Cockpit?

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, centos8, cockpit

I've installed Cockpit, Cockpit-machines and Virt-viewer on my CentOS 8 and successfully connected to my KVM server in Firefox on Windows 10. But i can not find a way to open graphical console of my VM in fullscreen. Is there a way to do this at all?

Comment: Proxmox does this from the box, btw.

Comment: Sadly, not currently